# How can I display submenu in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu

I want to create a menu with a submenu in asp.net. I wrote this code but show all element in page
I want when mouseover on item1, item2 displayed (submenu)

But my code doesn't work

```
 <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="2">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="item1" Value="item1">
              <asp:MenuItem Text="item2" Value="item2">

        </asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="item3" Value="item3"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
    </asp:Menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another `<asp:MenuItem ></asp:menuItem>` combination between two others. In your post above you are missing an opening `<asp:MenuItem>`. I see this:

```
</asp:MenuItem>
</asp:MenuItem>
```

**UPDATE AFTER YOUR COMMENT:**
I would think this should work:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="2">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="item1" Value="item1"> 
            <asp:MenuItem Text="item2" Value="item2"></asp:MenuItem>
        </asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="item3" Value="item3"></asp:MenuItem> 
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Comment: when I rwmove StaticDisplayLevels="2" solved problem

Comment: dang, I looked into that and was tempted to ask about it. No points for me.
I'm happy you figured this out!

Comment: It's okay, I'm glad I discovered it myself :D

Answer (score 2):

when I remove StaticDisplayLevels="2" .. solved my problem

```
            </asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="item3" Value="item3"></asp:MenuItem>
        </Items>
    </asp:Menu>
```